# How can I log data to a thumb drive?

Tags: arduino-uno, usb, data, logging

I am working on a project where I need to log data, but I was wondering if it is possible to log that data to a thumb drive? I know that I can log data to an SD card, but I thought a thumb drive would be more accessible to users who wish to obtain the data. And if it is possible to log to a thumb drive, could it be done in CSV format?
The data is just sensor data.

Comment: they make tiny readers that convert sd/microsd into usb drives, in about the same form factor as a thumb drive. not exactly the same thing, but way easier and cheaper to interface with an MCU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle you can log to a thumb drive any data you want, binary and text (thus also CSV).

However, the Arduino Uno does not support connecting a USB stick directly. If you want to connect a USB stick, you need a so called USB Host shield (for Arduino).

More information can be read on the Arduino site at this page:

https://docs.arduino.cc/retired/shields/arduino-usb-host-shield

Answer (score 2):

[Updated]

As an alternative to a Uno host shield, changing to a different Arduino MCU may also assist. USB host capabilty is needed for communicating with thumb drives.

[Some Arduino models](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-to-tell-if-a-board-has-native-usb-support-for-a-midi-project-with-a-mac/667494) have a native USB port (e.g., Arduino Due, Arduino Leonardo, Arduino Micro, Arduino Nano 33 IOT, Arduino Zero, Arduino MKR Zero, Arduino MKR1000 ... ) which will work as a USB client device role.

A smaller set of MCU can act as either a USB client or host (e.g., Arduino Due, Arduino Portenta, ...). There is a [USBHost](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/usbhost/) library for Arduino Due listed in the Arduino Reference. Documentation for Arduino Portenta in USB host mode is [here](https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/portenta-h7/usb-host).

[Here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/usb-host-due-support-for-mass-storage-devices-thumbdrives/635331) is a discussion (and reference to an alternative library) regarding using a Due to write files to a thumb drive.

Of course an adapter cable or a thumb drive with a physical connector matching the native USB port on the selected MCU is required. Both are commonly available.

See also [Can the Arduino interface with USB devices without the USB host shield?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/24177/can-the-arduino-interface-with-usb-devices-without-the-usb-host-shield)

Comment: For the Micro and Leonardo, the datasheet of the ATmega32U4 says its USB controller “Supports full-speed and low-speed _Device_ role”. I see no mention of support for the _host_ role. Are you sure they can act as a host?

Comment: Hi Edgar, no my experience has been with the Due, and so I relied on the linked discussion for the list of other MCU with native USB. I’ll edit my answer. Thanks. Do you know of a list of MCU with host capable native USB?

Comment: No, sorry. My experience with USB-capable Arduinos is limited to playing with the [Keyboard](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Keyboard) library on a Micro. I just learned that the Due is host-capable, thanks to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help!